# Starting with Node.js and CouchDB without libraries like nano or cradle

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, couchdb-nano

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting ' bad_request invalid_json' error when trying to insert document into CouchDB from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647656/getting-bad-request-invalid-json-error-when-trying-to-insert-document-into-co)

The highest voted answer on 
[CouchDB and Node.js - What module do you recommend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532209/couchdb-and-node-js-what-module-do-you-recommend)
recommends not to use libraries such as nano or cradle for starting with Node.js and CouchDB.

However I haven't found any tutorial on how to perform standard operations for all DBMSes like create database, create table, add and view data etc. programmatically.

EDIT: (partial answer) after installing and starting CouchDB go to `http://localhost:5984/_utils/script/couch.js`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should start by reading the [CouchDB book](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/index.html).

No idea why you don't want to use a module: I think you took an answer out of context (an answer that is probably one year old) and made your decision not to use a module.

That is not likely to be helpful to get stuff done. :) You are just repeating work that is done, and issues that have been fixed, etc.

If you want to learn CouchDB, read the book. You can read nano's source as it maps really closely to the API and should be easy to read, but the book is the full way to go.

If by any reason you decide you still want to implement your own module to do what others already do well, go for it :)

If instead you are looking for resources on using nano there are quite a few:

- readme: [github](https://github.com/dscape/nano/blob/master/README.md)
- screencast: [couchdb and nano](http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/30-couchdb-and-nano.html#video)
- article: [nano - a minimalistic couchdb client for nodejs](http://writings.nunojob.com/2011/08/nano-minimalistic-couchdb-client-for-nodejs.html)
- article: [getting started with node.js and couchdb](http://writings.nunojob.com/2011/09/getting-started-with-nodejs-and-couchdb.html)
- article: [document update handler support](http://jackhq.tumblr.com/post/16035106690/nano-v1-2-x-document-update-handler-support-v1-2-x)
- article: [nano 3](http://writings.nunojob.com/2012/05/Nano-3.html)
- article: [securing a site with couchdb cookie authentication using node.js and nano](http://mahoney.eu/2012/05/23/couchdb-cookie-authentication-nodejs-nano/)
- article: [adding copy to nano](http://blog.jlank.com/2012/07/04/adding-copy-to-nano/)
- article: [how to update a document with nano](http://writings.nunojob.com/2012/07/How-To-Update-A-Document-With-Nano-The-CouchDB-Client-for-Node.js.html)
- article: [mock http integration testing in node.js using nock and specify](http://writings.nunojob.com/2012/05/Mock-HTTP-Integration-Testing-in-Node.js-using-Nock-and-Specify.html)
- article: [mock testing couchdb in node.js with nock and tap](http://writings.nunojob.com/2011/12/Mock-Testing-CouchDB-Using-NodeJS-With-Nock-And-TAP.html)

Comment: Jason's advice is still valid regardless of the answer's age. Especially with Node.js' there's no real need for a library that just wraps the excellent HTTP API.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [`Ruben Verborgh`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647656/getting-bad-request-invalid-json-error-when-trying-to-insert-document-into-co#answer-11649320), I compiled micro-tutorial from several sources myself.

```
var http = require('http')
var sys = require('sys')


var couchdbPath = 'http://localhost:5984/'

request = require('request')
h = {accept: 'application/json', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
request(
  {uri: couchdbPath + '_all_dbs', headers:h}, 
  function(err, response, body) { console.log(sys.inspect(JSON.parse(body))); }
)

// add database
request(
  {uri: couchdbPath + 'dbname', method:'PUT', headers:h},
  function (err, response, body) {
    if (err)
      throw err;
    if (response.statusCode !== 201)
      throw new Error("Could not create database. " + body);
  }
)

// Modify existing document
var options = {
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5984,
  path: "/dbname",
  headers: {"content-type": "application/json"},
  method: "PUT"
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  //console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write(JSON.stringify({
  "_id":"rabbit",
  "_rev":"4-8cee219da7e61616b7ab22c3614b9526",
  "Subject":"I like Plankton"
}));

req.end();
```

I used following documentation:

- [`http.request()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)
- [CouchDB Complete HTTP API Reference](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Complete_HTTP_API_Reference)

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer or a question on its own?

Comment: Answer. Very strange that such example is not available in docs. The impression is that there is no beginners in CouchDB+Node.js+web-in-general

Comment: thanks.. your answered opened an ocean of resources

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB is not an SQL database engine. It's in the family of the "NoSQL" ones.

You don't do select, you don't create tables, etc.

It's completely different.

It's actually using a REST API to work. Like, to access all the documents, you access them using an HTTP GET on the following URL: http://some.server/someDbName/_all_docs

For a more thorough introduction, I suggest looking for "CouchDB tutorial" on Google.

You'll find good links like [this one](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-couchdb/) or [this one](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/3767157786/couchdb-tutorial-getting-started-with-couchdb). (I'm not vouching for any, they just look good as an introduction.)

To make an http request in node.js, you can use the [`request`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) method of the built-in `http` module. A shortcut method is `http.get`, which you can use like this:

```
var http = require( 'http' );

http.get( 'http://some.url/with/params', function( res ) {
    // res has the values returned
});
```

**Edit after reading your code:**

Firstly, the doc you're using if outdated. Node is at v0.8, not 0.4.

Secondly, your `request = require('request')` must give some problems (does the module exist?). I don't think the first part is even executed.

Thirdly, just try a GET request for now. Something like:

```
var http = require( 'http' );
http.get( 'http://localhost:5984/_all_dbs', function( res ) {
    console.log( res );
});
```

See if it's working. If it is, you already know how to use couchdb ;)

Lastly, your request at the end doesn't seem wrong. Maybe it's related to `require('request')` though, so I don't know.

Comment: I approximately know, what NoSQL mean, sorry for using wrong language. Link that you suggest does not provide programmatic approach, only curl.

Comment: programmatic approach: do HTTP requests. curl does http requests, it's the same.

Comment: but I struggle to do this programmatically for several hours. I hope soon I post answer myself.

Comment: Too simple :). I'll post my code

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem wrong, but it is :( and I even don't know how to "debug" it. Drastic difference with Python experience :(( . I decided to use nano.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few hands-on examples, thoughts and code-snippets which should help in your study

[Simple Blog with Coffeescript, Express and CoudbDB](http://blog.koostudios.com/?p=398)

[Thoughts on development using CouchDB and Nodejs](http://tbranyen.com/post/thoughts-on-development-using-couchdb-with-nodejs)

[Bind CouchDB and Node.js](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/glue-bind-couchdb-and-nodejs)

[Getting Started with Node.js, Express and CouchDB](http://www.bytemuse.com/2011/06/getting-started-with-node-js-express-and-couchdb/) - this link does not seem to be accessible now, but it seems a temporary issue.

Here's one on testing CouchDB - [Mock testing CouchDB using Node.js](http://writings.nunojob.com/2011/12/Mock-Testing-CouchDB-Using-NodeJS-With-Nock-And-TAP.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: First link - uses cradle, second - not a solution, third - uses nano.

Comment: Have been compiling useful resources on Node.js for around a year now and my guess is the list is pretty much what's available on CouchDB and Node.js

Comment: almypal your list is lacking quite a few. i'll post them in a separate answer