# Getting ' bad_request invalid_json' error when trying to insert document into CouchDB from Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, couchdb

I'm trying to insert a document into CouchDB. While executing this code CouchDB returns the following error:

```
STATUS: 400    
BODY: {"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
```

My code:

```
var http = require('http')


var options = {
"host": "localhost",
"port": "5984",
"path": "/chinese",
"headers": {"content-type": "application/json"},
"method": "PUT",
"body": JSON.stringify({
    "_id":"rabbit",
    "_rev":"2-c31d8f403d44d1082b3b178ebef8d329",
    "Subject":"I like Plankton"
})
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

What's wrong?

EDIT: I need to update data, so I replaced POST to PUT.

Comment: That's CouchDB returning the error message, not Node.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are writing `'data\n'` as the body of your request, and that's not valid JSON indeed.

Probably, you meant:

```
req.write(JSON.stringify({"data": "somedata"}));
```

instead of passing this as the `body` parameter of the options.

Comment: No, the error occures in preceding code, it remains even if I comment out this line.

Comment: Yes, it also occurs if you comment out the line. Because you're not sending a body then, and that's also invalid JSON.
Therefore, I suggested you *replace* the line `req.write('data\n');` with the code above. Can you try that instead of just commenting out?

Comment: Thank you very much, this simple operation drank from me a liter of blood. But can we reorganize code in such a way that "body" and other options lie together?

Comment: What I'd recommend in that case, is to add a function that abstracts this behavior. Something like `function store(path, contents)`, to which you pass your path and body. The function then does the request, JSON encoding, etc.

Comment: In my case I had `\'` in my `startkey` and `endkey` values, and `request` did not translate those over to `'`..