# CouchDb unhandled 'error' event - Node js

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I'm new to Node and CouchDb and I'm trying to get my hands on it. 
I'm struggling to make a piece of code to work. 
I would like to create a table `users`, insert a new user and 'at the same time' getting another user.

I'm getting this error when starting up `node app.js` :

```
antoine@ubuntu:~/projects/couchDb$ node app.js 
Database users exists.
{"error":"conflict","reason":"Document update conflict."}
Leaving saveDoc

events.js:48
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (http.js:1107:15)
    at Socket.onend (http.js:1188:27)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:369:26)
```

---

And here is my very code, is there something wrong?
(When I remove the getDoc function the error goes away)
I'm using couchDB 1.0.1 and node 0.6.12

The `jdoe4` and `jdoe` documents are already present in the `users` database.

```
var dbHost = "127.0.0.1";
var dbPort = 5984;
var dbName = 'users';

var couchdb = require('felix-couchdb');
var client = couchdb.createClient(dbPort, dbHost);

var user = {
  name: {
    first: 'John',
    last: 'Doe'
  }
}

var db = client.db(dbName);

db.exists(function(err, exists) {
  if (!exists) {
    db.create();
    console.log('Database ' + dbName + ' created.');
  } else {
    console.log('Database ' + dbName + ' exists.');
  }

  db.saveDoc('jdoe4', user, function(err, doc) {
    if( err) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        } else {
          console.log('Saved user.');
        }
        console.log('Leaving saveDoc');
    });

    db.getDoc('jdoe', function(err,doc) {
        if( err) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
        }
        console.log('Leaving getDoc');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a library problem => [Github Issue Socket Hangout](https://github.com/felixge/node-couchdb/issues/38)

[Look here if you dont know which library fit more your needs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532209/couchdb-and-node-js-what-module-do-you-recommend)

Answer (score 0):

I quickly realized that felix-couchdb is not compatible with node 8 (I know you're not using version 8, but you will someday), so I switched to nano couchdb and here's the following code:

1. It will check if the db is created
2. It will insert only if the key given is unique
3. It will get the user with a key

   ```
   var couchdb = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984')
     , dbName = 'users'
     , db = couchdb.use(dbName)
     ;

   var user = {
       name: {
           first: 'John',
           last: 'Doe'
       }
   }

   couchdb.db.create(dbName, function(err, db_body) {

   db.insert(user, 'jdoe4', function(err, doc, header) {
       if( err) {
         console.log('Cannot save user');
       } else {
         console.log('Saved user.');
       }
       console.log('Leaving saveDoc');
   });

   db.get('jdoe', function(err, doc) {
       if( err) {
           console.log('Cannot get user');
       } else {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
       }
       console.log('Leaving getDoc');
   });

   });
   ```

One thing worth noting is that, while this will get them at the "same time," it's still making 3 requests to the db, 1 to check if it exists, 1 to insert (or not), 1 to get.