# Has anyone found or developed a good couchdb manager in node-js?

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I would like to manage my couchdb with a good-looking nodejs manager.

It should have these functions:

- Create document.
- Delete document.
- Dump the whole Database
- Backup the whole Database

Comment: Duplicate?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532209/couchdb-and-node-js-what-module-do-you-recommend

Comment: What's wrong with the Futon? Does all that and more and is part of the official package.

Comment: @Nick: i dont search a connector. I search a Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Futon](https://www.npmjs.org/package/futon), the built-in manager has all the functionality you require. Futon has a web interface and can be accessed by running `couchdb` and then pointing your web browser to `http://localhost:5984/_utils/`